# Which of these words would you use in BrE vs AmE? Are there any regional differences associated with these words?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Fridge or refrigerator
/ mini-fridge or compact refrigerator
/ garden hose or hose pipe or water hose

Answer (score 1):

Based on information from google ngrams, and assuming that you're interested in the current usage (historical is also shown in the plots, if not).

These screenshots may be a little small to read some of the text clearly, sorry about that. Each set of two ngram plots shows the results from the British corpus, then the results from the American corpus.

"Refrigerator" is quite strongly preferred in the American English corpus, while the British English corpus shows a (weaker) preference for "fridge":

[image: Fridge vs Refrigerator - British English]

[image: Fridge vs Refrigerator - US English]

"Compact refrigerator" wasn't found at all in the British corpus. In the American corpus it exists, but is much less used than "minifridge" or "mini-fridge". The British corpus strongly prefers "mini-fridge" over "minifridge", while the American corpus has a strong preference in the other direction:

[image: minifridge - UK]
[image: minifridge - US]

"Garden hose" is comfortably the most common in both American and British corpuses. In the British corpus "hose pipe" and "water hose" are roughly as common as each other, while in the American corpus "hose pipe" barely registers:

[image: hose - UK]
[image: hose - US]

The usual caveats for ngram data apply: the corpus isn't necessarily representative of everyday speech, words or phrases may occur in other contexts than those desired (although that seems unlikely to be an issue in this particular case), and generalisations from a small dataset should be taken with a pinch of salt (relevant especially to the search for "minifridge" vs. "mini-fridge" vs. "compact refrigerator" in the British corpus).

Those caveats in mind, I can at least state that as a native BrE speaker, none of the results from the British corpus strike me as surprising (except perhaps how common "refrigerator" is - I suspect that's a result of the corpus being biased towards formal texts)

Comment: I heartily concur, *especially* with your surmise about the commonality of "refrigerator" in the results being influenced by formality of the analytically available corpus.